# Scala/Java reflective programming: invoke constructor by typecasted arguments

Tags: java, scala, reflection, casting

In the library json4s, I intend to write a weakly typed deserializer for some malformed data (mostly the result of XML -> JSON conversions)

I want the dynamic program to get the type information of a given constructor (easy, e.g. 'Int'), apply it on a parsed string (e.g. "12.51"), automatically convert string into the type (in this case 12.51 should be typecasted to 13), then call the constructor.

I come up with the following implementation:

```
import org.json4s.JsonAST.{JDecimal, JDouble, JInt, JString}
import org.json4s._
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

object WeakNumDeserializer extends Serializer[Any] {

  def cast[T](cc: Class[T], v: Any): Option[T] = {
    implicit val ctg: ClassTag[T] = ClassTag(cc)

    try {
      Some(v.asInstanceOf[T])
    }
    catch {
      case e: Throwable =>
        None
    }
  }

  override def deserialize(implicit format: Formats): PartialFunction[(TypeInfo, JValue), Any] = Function.unlift{
    tuple: (TypeInfo, JValue) =>

      tuple match {
        case (TypeInfo(cc, _), JInt(v)) =>
          cast(cc, v)
        case (TypeInfo(cc, _), JDouble(v)) =>
          cast(cc, v)
        case (TypeInfo(cc, _), JDecimal(v)) =>
          cast(cc, v)
        case (TypeInfo(cc, _), JString(v)) =>
          cast(cc, v.toDouble)
        case _ =>
          None
      }
  }
}
```

However executing the above code on a real Double => Int case always yield IllegalArgumentException. Debugging reveals that the line:

```
v.asInstanceOf[T]
```

does not convert Double type to Int in memory, it remains as a Double number after type erasure, and after it is used in reflection to call the constructor it triggers the error.

How do I bypass this and make the reflective function figuring this out?
Is there a way to tell the Java compiler to actually convert it into an Int type?

UPDATE: to help validating your answer I've posted my test cases:

```
case class StrStr(
                   a: String,
                   b: String
                 )

case class StrInt(
                   a: String,
                   b: Int
                 )

case class StrDbl(
                   a: String,
                   b: Double
                 )

case class StrIntArray(
                        a: String,
                        b: Array[Int]
                      )

case class StrIntSeq(
                      a: String,
                      b: Seq[Int]
                    )

case class StrIntSet(
                      a: String,
                      b: Set[Int]
                    )

class WeakSerializerSuite extends FunSuite with TestMixin{

  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats ++ Seq(StringToNumberDeserializer, ElementToArrayDeserializer)

  import org.json4s.Extraction._

  test("int to String") {

    val d1 = StrInt("a", 12)
    val json = decompose(d1)

    val d2 = extract[StrStr](json)
    d2.toString.shouldBe("StrStr(a,12)")
  }

  test("string to int") {
    val d1 = StrStr("a", "12")
    val json = decompose(d1)

    val d2 = extract[StrInt](json)
    d2.toString.shouldBe("StrInt(a,12)")
  }

  test("double to int") {
    val d1 = StrDbl("a", 12.51)
    val json = decompose(d1)

    val d2 = extract[StrInt](json)
    d2.toString.shouldBe("StrInt(a,12)")
  }

  test("int to int array") {
    val d1 = StrInt("a", 12)
    val json = decompose(d1)

    val d2 = extract[StrIntArray](json)
    d2.copy(b = null).toString.shouldBe("StrIntArray(a,null)")
  }

  test("int to int seq") {
    val d1 = StrInt("a", 12)
    val json = decompose(d1)

    val d2 = extract[StrIntSeq](json)
    d2.toString.shouldBe("StrIntSeq(a,List(12))")
  }

  test("int to int set") {
    val d1 = StrInt("a", 12)
    val json = decompose(d1)

    val d2 = extract[StrIntSet](json)
    d2.toString.shouldBe("StrIntSet(a,Set(12))")
  }

  test("string to int array") {
    val d1 = StrStr("a", "12")
    val json = decompose(d1)

    val d2 = extract[StrIntArray](json)
    d2.copy(b = null).toString.shouldBe("StrIntArray(a,null)")
  }

  test("string to int seq") {
    val d1 = StrStr("a", "12")
    val json = decompose(d1)

    val d2 = extract[StrIntSeq](json)
    d2.toString.shouldBe("StrIntSeq(a,List(12))")
  }

  test("string to int set") {
    val d1 = StrStr("a", "12")
    val json = decompose(d1)

    val d2 = extract[StrIntSet](json)
    d2.toString.shouldBe("StrIntSet(a,Set(12))")
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the first solution, TL:DR: its totally absurd & illogical, and absolutely full of boilerplates for a established strongly typed language. Please post your answer deemed any better:

```
abstract class WeakDeserializer[T: Manifest] extends Serializer[T] {

//  final val tpe = implicitly[Manifest[T]]
//  final val clazz = tpe.runtimeClass

  // cannot serialize
  override def serialize(implicit format: Formats): PartialFunction[Any, JValue] = PartialFunction.empty
}

object StringToNumberDeserializer extends WeakDeserializer[Any] {

  override def deserialize(implicit format: Formats): PartialFunction[(TypeInfo, JValue), Any] = {

    case (TypeInfo(cc, _), JString(v)) =>
      cc match {
        case java.lang.Byte.TYPE => v.toByte
        case java.lang.Short.TYPE => v.toShort
        case java.lang.Character.TYPE => v.toInt.toChar
        case java.lang.Integer.TYPE => v.toInt
        case java.lang.Long.TYPE => v.toLong
        case java.lang.Float.TYPE => v.toFloat
        case java.lang.Double.TYPE => v.toDouble
        case java.lang.Boolean.TYPE => v.toBoolean
        //TODO: add boxed type
      }
  }
}

object ElementToArrayDeserializer extends WeakDeserializer[Any] {

  val listClass = classOf[List[_]]
  val seqClass = classOf[Seq[_]]
  val setClass = classOf[Set[_]]
  val arrayListClass = classOf[java.util.ArrayList[_]]

  override def deserialize(implicit format: Formats): PartialFunction[(TypeInfo, JValue), Any] = {

    case (ti@ TypeInfo(this.listClass, _), jv) =>
      List(extractInner(ti, jv, format))

    case (ti@ TypeInfo(this.seqClass, _), jv) =>
      Seq(extractInner(ti, jv, format))

    case (ti@ TypeInfo(this.setClass, _), jv) =>
      Set(extractInner(ti, jv, format))

    case (ti@ TypeInfo(this.arrayListClass, _), jv) =>
      import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

      new java.util.ArrayList[Any](List(extractInner(ti, jv, format)).asJava)

    case (ti@ TypeInfo(cc, _), jv) if cc.isArray =>
      val a = Array(extractInner(ti, jv, format))
      mkTypedArray(a, firstTypeArg(ti))
  }

  def mkTypedArray(a: Array[_], typeArg: ScalaType) = {
    import java.lang.reflect.Array.{newInstance => newArray}

    a.foldLeft((newArray(typeArg.erasure, a.length), 0)) { (tuple, e) => {
      java.lang.reflect.Array.set(tuple._1, tuple._2, e)
      (tuple._1, tuple._2 + 1)
    }}._1
  }

  def extractInner(ti: TypeInfo, jv: JValue, format: Formats): Any = {
    val result = extract(jv, firstTypeArg(ti))(format)
    result
  }

  def firstTypeArg(ti: TypeInfo): ScalaType = {
    val tpe = ScalaType.apply(ti)
    val firstTypeArg = tpe.typeArgs.head
    firstTypeArg
  }
}
```